# Websocket Client in OSGI

Tags: java, websocket, osgi, apache-karaf, tyrus

I have currently implemented websocket client using tyrus client and the websockets client works correctly outside OSGI environment.

The problem is that the websocket doesn't run on apache karaf.
I have installed all the dependencies for websocket client.The list is

```
 ID | State     | Lvl | Version        | Name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 52 | Active    |  80 | 4.3.0          | Apache Felix Dependency Manager
 96 | Active    |  80 | 1.0            | WebSocket server API
 97 | Active    |  80 | 1.1.0          | Tyrus Server
 98 | Active    |  80 | 1.1.0          | Tyrus Core
 99 | Active    |  80 | 1.1.0          | Tyrus Container SPI
100 | Active    |  80 | 1.1.0          | Tyrus WebSocket Core
102 | Active    |  80 | 1.1.0          | Tyrus Grizzly Container
103 | Active    |  80 | 2.3.3          | grizzly-framework
104 | Active    |  80 | 2.3.3          | grizzly-http
105 | Active    |  80 | 2.3.3          | grizzly-http-server
106 | Active    |  80 | 2.3.3          | grizzly-rcm
118 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.8          | Apache Aries SPI Fly Dynamic Weaving Bundle
134 | Active    |  80 | 1.1.0          | Tyrus Client
135 | Installed |  80 | 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | rna-websocket-client
```

The tyrus client provides the implementation via ServiceLoader.
So i am using the Apache Aries SPI Fly Dynamic Weaving Bundle to get the implementation. But I am still getting the **Could not find an implementation class.** error.

On investigation i found that the tyrus client doesnt add the

```
Provide-Capability: osgi.serviceloader; osgi.serviceloader="javax.websocket.ContainerProvider"
```

to the manifest which is required to inform the processing bundle about the service being provided.
In my rna-websocket-client bundle i have added the

```
<Require-Capability>osgi.serviceloader; filter:="(osgi.serviceloader=javax.websocket.ContainerProvider)";cardinality:=multiple,osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor)"</Require-Capability>.
```

This would be required to inform the aries dynamic weaving bundle that we consume the javax.websocket.ContainerProvider service.

Is this the correct way of running websockets in OSGI or is there any other approach for running websockets in OSGI?
Any insights on the issue would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [explanation how to use websockets with jetty](https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools/wiki/Websocket-with-jetty-9-and-osgi) at bndtools.
Maybe that can help.

Comment: The websocket client worked with client example mentioned in the link with minor modifications. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Karaf uses Pax-Web as Web-Container Mediation Layer. 
Therefore it's best to take a look at the corresponding Pax-Web Examples and integration tests:
[WebSocketIntegrationTest](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/jetty/WebSocketIntegrationTest.java)
[WebSocketWhiteBoardIntegrationTest](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/jetty/WebSocketWhiteBoardIntegrationTest.java#L62-L69)

or a corresponding sample:
[KarafWebsocketSample](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/karaf-websocket)

Comment: Makes sense. That should be easier to apply in karaf.

Comment: Already implemented the websocket client with jetty. Will also check this one once I get some time.